JSON file tree recursion for extracting the table and column name in pyhton
I have written the below code something I am missing I don't know what, the current_table and column_name value is coming before elif condition but after inside the elif why it is not coming I am not getting. Please help what is missing and why the current_table and column_name values are not retaining till end of one loop.
Please help.
import re
import json


def traverse(node, current_table=None):
    """
    Traverse the SQL structure to extract tables and columns.
    """
    if isinstance(node, dict):
        for key, value in node.items():
            # If it's a table reference, set current_table
            if key == 'table_reference' and isinstance(value, list):
                # Join parts like table alias and table name
                table_name_parts = [v.get('naked_identifier') for v in value if v.get('naked_identifier')]
                table_name = ".".join(table_name_parts)
                if table_name:
                    current_table = table_name
                    print(f"Table detected: {current_table}")  # Debugging

            # Handle column references
            elif key == 'column_reference' and isinstance(value, dict):
                # Extract column name directly from the structure
                column_name = value.get('naked_identifier')  # Assuming column name is stored here
                if column_name:  # Ensure column name is valid
                    print(f"Column detected: {column_name} for table: {current_table}")  # Debugging
                    if current_table:
                        if current_table not in tables_columns_map:
                            tables_columns_map[current_table] = []
                        tables_columns_map[current_table].append(column_name)
                    else:
                        print(f"Error: current_table is None when processing column {column_name}")

            # Recurse into subnodes
            elif isinstance(value, (list, dict)):
                traverse(value, current_table)  # Continue processing

    elif isinstance(node, list):
        for item in node:
            traverse(item, current_table)


# Example usage:
parsed_data = {
    "select_statement": [
        {"column_reference": {"naked_identifier": "MI_KEY_ACC_SWITCHING"}},
        {"column_reference": {"naked_identifier": "CURRENCY"}},
        {"table_reference": [{"naked_identifier": "A_MPAY_BUKDB.ACC_SWITCHING"}]},
        {"column_reference": {"naked_identifier": "DEPARTMENT"}}
    ]
}

tables_columns_map = {}
traverse(parsed_data)
print("Final tables_columns_map:")
print(tables_columns_map)


Why do you import re and json, if you don‘t use it?

initially I was trying to parse the sql query with the help of regualr expression, so was using re forgot to delete and as the main json file was having some extra quotation so was trying to handle that throught json module. sorry forgot to delete those libraries.

@Hermann12 can you suggest something?
